# validate if another two mail exist

Tags: r

I am trying to validate if two mail ID exist with same name but not working for me , if we have any other solution...??
but I also have NA's  and blank cells I want to ignore those also.

```
df <- data.frame(EMP.ID = c(88111,"BBB4477","BBB4058","BBB5832","BBB0338","BBB1814","BBB6543",875430,875970,"BBB0243","BBB1943","BBB9344","BBB9701","BBB1814","BBB8648","BBB4373","BBB7270","BBB6165","BBB7460","BBB7528","BBB6092","BBB7203"),
                 name = c("adam,link","tt,dy","adam,link","gbesada","dojeda","    slew"," alpucheta","    rzona","jachaval","allo,nuny","mbautis","rgrandinettizzy","jali","kintom","namoti,mew","rohan,sah",NA,NA,NA,NA,"",""),
                 email = c("link.adam@gmail.com","dy.tt@abcd.com","link.adam@gmail.com","gbesada@abcd.com","dojeda@abcd.com"," slew@abcd.com"," alpucheta@abcd.com"," rzona@abcd.com","jachaval@abcd.com","allo@abcd.com","mbautis@abcd.com","rgrandinettizzy@abcd.com","jali@abcd.com","kintom@abcd.com","namoti@abcd.com","sah.rohan@abcd.com","","","",NA,"",""))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output screenshot data doesn't quite match the `df` that you have provided. I modified the `df` a little to match it.

You can specify multiple logical conditions inside `ifelse()` using `&` for "AND" or `|` for "OR". In this case, you just want "AND". The solution is as follows:

```r
df <- data.frame(EMP.ID = c(88111,"BBB4477","BBB4058","BBB5832","BBB0338","BBB1814","BBB6543",875430,875970,"BBB0243","BBB1943","BBB9344","BBB9701","BBB1814","BBB8648","BBB4373","BBB7270","BBB6165","BBB7460","BBB7528","BBB6092","BBB7203"),
                 name = c("adam,link","tt,dy","adam,link","gbesada","dojeda","    slew"," alpucheta","    rzona","jachaval","allo,nuny","mbautis","rgrandinettizzy","jali","kintom","namoti,mew","rohan,sah","gbesada",NA,NA,NA,"",""),
                 email = c("link.adam@gmail.com","dy.tt@abcd.com","link.adam@gmail.com","gbesada@abcd.com","dojeda@abcd.com"," slew@abcd.com"," alpucheta@abcd.com"," rzona@abcd.com","jachaval@abcd.com","allo@abcd.com","mbautis@abcd.com","rgrandinettizzy@abcd.com","jali@abcd.com","kintom@abcd.com","namoti@abcd.com","sah.rohan@abcd.com","gbesada@gmail.com","","",NA,"",""))

# solution
library(dplyr) # to use mutate() and pipe operators
library(stringr) # to use str_extract()

df %>% mutate(
    `duplicated mailid` = ifelse(
        duplicated(str_extract(email, "([^@]+)")) & 
            !is.na(email) & 
            nchar(as.character(email)) > 0, 
        "Duplicate email username exists", ""
        )
    )
#    EMP.ID            name                    email               duplicated mailid
#1    88111       adam,link      link.adam@gmail.com                                
#2  BBB4477           tt,dy           dy.tt@abcd.com                                
#3  BBB4058       adam,link      link.adam@gmail.com Duplicate email username exists
#4  BBB5832         gbesada         gbesada@abcd.com                                
#5  BBB0338          dojeda          dojeda@abcd.com                                
#6  BBB1814            slew            slew@abcd.com                                
#7  BBB6543       alpucheta       alpucheta@abcd.com                                
#8   875430           rzona           rzona@abcd.com                                
#9   875970        jachaval        jachaval@abcd.com                                
#10 BBB0243       allo,nuny            allo@abcd.com                                
#11 BBB1943         mbautis         mbautis@abcd.com                                
#12 BBB9344 rgrandinettizzy rgrandinettizzy@abcd.com                                
#13 BBB9701            jali            jali@abcd.com                                
#14 BBB1814          kintom          kintom@abcd.com                                
#15 BBB8648      namoti,mew          namoti@abcd.com                                
#16 BBB4373       rohan,sah       sah.rohan@abcd.com                                
#17 BBB7270         gbesada        gbesada@gmail.com Duplicate email username exists
#18 BBB6165            <NA>                                                         
#19 BBB7460            <NA>                                                         
#20 BBB7528            <NA>                     <NA>                                
#21 BBB6092                                                                         
#22 BBB7203
```

**Breakdown of the multiple logical conditions**
`duplicated(str_extract(email, "([^@]+)"))` allows you to find instances when usernames within email addresses appear the second or more times, even when the email domains differ (*username@domain.com*).
`!is.na(email)` allows you to ignore NA in the emails.
`nchar(as.character(email)) > 0` allows you to ignore blanks in the emails.